# How to Rename Bulk Files using CMD

Tags: cmd, batch-rename

I have a bunch of sql files that I would like to rename as they have the schema name at the start of the file like the following:

```
SCHEMA.TABLE.sql
```

Which I want to be renamed to:

```
TABLE.sql
```

Unfortunately as I am trying to do this on my work laptop, I can't download any third party software such Bulk Rename Utility so I am trying to do this using CMD.

What I attempted was the following:

```
REN SCHEMA.*.sql *.sql
```

which looks like it finds a match but nothing changes. So not sure what I need to change so would appreciate any advice as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: Well, what do you want the new names to be? do you want to remove the `SCHEMA.` part? if so, try this: `for /F "eol=| tokens=1* delims=." %I in ('dir /B "*.*.sql"') do ren "%I.%J" "%J"` (don't forget to double the `%`-signs when you want to use this code in a batch file). You may be interested in this post on Super User: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/a/475875)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Apologies, meant to add that I would like remove the SCHEMA name completely and just have table name on its own. Will attempt what you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ren` command](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) interprets the `*` in the target pattern `*.sql` so that it matches all source characters up to the last `.`, meaning that it matches the portion `SCHEMA.TABLE` of your sample. Therefore, the target name equals the source name.

Consult this great post on Super User: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/a/475875)

---

To remove the `SCHEMA.` part from your file names you need to use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
for /F "eol=| tokens=1* delims=." %I in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.*.sql"') do ren "%I.%J" "%J"
```

This fails in case there are more than one `.`, like in `SCHEMA..TABLE.sql`, for example.

Do not forget to **double the `%`-signs** when you want to use that code in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)!

Answer (score 0):

1.This can be done using powershell script pretty easily. Copy following script, edit $path to the path where the files are located.

```
$path = 'D:\MyFolder\My docs\testdelete'
$pathObject = get-childitem -path $path | where-object {$_.Psiscontainer -eq $false}
foreach($file in $pathObject)
{
    $fileNameArray = $file.Name.Split(".")
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ($fileNameArray[1]+".sql")
}
```

2.Next save this script in a file named, say testrename.ps1. Open cmd change directory to the location where you saved testren.ps1 file and further run following command:

```
powershell -file "testren.ps1"
```

Here $path is the path where the files are located. $pathObject will get all the files in the said location. Further we iterate each file, split the name to get what comes after 'schema' and further rename it. If cmd is not a restriction then 1st script can also be directly run by opening powershell window on windows, copy paste the script after modifying the path and hit Enter key. In this case step 2 is not required.

Comment: Unless you modify your answer to run from [[tag:cmd]], it is not valid for the question title or tags, please edit it accordingly.